# Packets difference between PTP and gPTP

Tags: wireshark, ptp

I'm trying to understand few things about gPTP (IEEE 802.1AS). I am using the open source implementation by AVnu (https://github.com/AVnu/gptp).

I looking on the packets using Wireshark, and they are parsed as PTPv2 packets.

Is there any protocol difference between the packets themselves that can be used to understand whether a certain traffic is gPTP or normal PTP? I know that gPTP only extends PTP, but I thought there would be a detectable difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

gPTP is [a profile of PTPv2](https://avb.statusbar.com/page/developer-faq/#what-is-the-difference-between-ptp-ptpv2-gptp-802-1as-and-ieee-1588); it implements some additional features.

Wireshark should be able to decode everything which may be of interest to you. If it does not, then you can [file an enhancement request](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: The question is whether there is a difference between the packets- that could be detectable by *anybody*. If the packets looks the same- Wireshark won't be able to decide which protocol it is, and it's ok, I guess.

Comment: AFAIK it's interoperable, so you might not be able to detect a difference. But perhaps someone with more experience with PTP will come by and answer.